# How to add CSS class to the HTML5 picture element

Tags: html, css

The code below uses the `picture` HTML5 element to display a different versions of an image, depending if the user uses a mobile device or a desktop.

**Question:** How can I make only mobile_image.png 10% the width of the viewport (window)? Why can't I add a css class or style tag to `source media`?

```
<div class="my_container">
<a href="#back_to_top">
<picture>
<source media="(max-width:767px)" srcset="mobile_image.png">
<source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="desktop_image.png">
<img src="fallback_image.png" alt="Back to Top">
</picture>
</a>
</div>
```

Using the code below - nothing!

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
.my_container {
width:10%;
height:auto;
}
}
```

Comment: The `picture` element and the corresponding source attributes are fairly new, so which version of which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Chrome 39. From what I see, the picture element at this point does not accept css styling? I can add a border to it, but can not set a width...

Comment: I don't have Chrome 39 here, so I'd have to update, but in Firefox 33 it works as expected, except that you need to refresh the window after a size change to see the new picture. It doesn't update the image automatically on the breakpoint. Could that be the problem in Chrome as well?

Comment: Or, is the problem that you expect the size of the image to scale with the size of the `picture`?

Comment: Thank you for your testing. Firefox does not support <picture> yet, it just uses the <img> element provided as fallback. I think I should start looking for other solutions, picture seems too much of an experiment right now..

Comment: Firefox 33 _does_ support `picture`! However, you will need to enable the about:config settings `dom.image.picture.enabled` and `dom.image.srcset.enabled` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If i'm understanding what you want correctly try targeting the img tag in the picture element then apply your styles to that.

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .my_container img {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Also add the polyfill so it will work cross browser - https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Comment: This answer saved me: it reminded me to set `height: auto`.

Answer (score 22):

You can also add classes to the "img src" line of the code:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="tablet_image.png">
   <source media="(min-width:992px)" srcset="desktop_image.png">
   <img src="fallback-mobile_image.png" alt="whatever" class="img-responsive center-block etc">
</picture>
```

The classes are then applied to whichever image is being rendered by the screen size.  Definitely helpful for when you're using a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.