# How to add style to webp images

Tags: html, css, webp

my code looks like

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/photo.webp">
  <source type="image/jpg" srcset="img/photo.jpg">
  <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="">
</picture >
```

I want to add class to this picture so I can use border-radius. how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add CSS class to the HTML5 picture element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008293/how-to-add-css-class-to-the-html5-picture-element)

Answer (score 1):

Put the class on the `<picture>` tag

```html
<picture class="classname">
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/photo.webp">
  <source type="image/jpg" srcset="img/photo.jpg">
  <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="" >
</picture>
```

Target the `<img>` tag in the CSS like this

```css
.classname img{
    styles here
}
```