# Styling Image size in the picture element

Tags: html, css, image

I’m new but eager to learn.
So, I’ve been learning html and css until I bumped into the so called picture element. (I’ve had no problems with the img element prior. When I want to set a width and height for my image which is very large btw, it’s not working with the width and height attributes. My image and the srcset attribute are inside the picture element so I really don’t know what to do. I also tried using sizes attribute but no use either. How do I style the size of my image in the picture element?? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008293/how-to-add-css-class-to-the-html5-picture-element

Comment: @BeulahEvanjalin suggestion is this is a duplicate question.  Voting to close this post. [How to add CSS class to the HTML5 picture element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008293/how-to-add-css-class-to-the-html5-picture-element)

Comment: @Zak I do not think this is a duplicate question. This question is about how to specify the size of the image in picture element. Although adding a css class is a solution but there are other ways.